# View Query on parent and child table

Tags: sql, view, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11G, I have below table structure

STATE_DEF table is parent table

```
TAX_DEF_ID  EFFECTIVE_DATE  REP_TYPE
1           9-Jan-12        R
2           15-Jan-12       W
```

and child table 'TAX_DETAIL' as below

```
TAX_DETAIL_ID   TAX_TYPE    DISTRIBUTION_TYPE   WH_RATE   TAX_DEF_ID
1               I           S                   0.1       1
2               I           P                   0.12      1
3               D           S                   0.2       1
4               D           P                   0.22      1
5               I           S                   0.3       2
6               I           P                   0.31      2
7               D           S                   0.4       2
8               D           P                   0.41      2
```

I want to create a view which will given output shown below

```
TAX_DEF_ID  EFFECTIVE_DATE  I_S_WH_RATE    I_P_WH_RATE  D_S_WH_RATE   D_P_WH_RATE
1           9-Jan-12        0.1            0.12         0.2           0.22
2           15-Jan-12       0.3            0.31         0.4           0.41
```

I had tried LISTAGG function but it would give me single column with concated columns. I am looking for the view definition which will give me rates in separate columns for a effective date.

I have been trying to get this output from couple of days. I would appretiate any help to achieve above result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    SD.TAX_DEF_ID,
    SD.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TYPE = 'I' AND DISTRIBUTION_TYPE = 'S' THEN WH_RATE ELSE 0 END) I_S_WH_RATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TYPE = 'I' AND DISTRIBUTION_TYPE = 'P' THEN WH_RATE ELSE 0 END) I_P_WH_RATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TYPE = 'D' AND DISTRIBUTION_TYPE = 'S' THEN WH_RATE ELSE 0 END) D_S_WH_RATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TYPE = 'D' AND DISTRIBUTION_TYPE = 'P' THEN WH_RATE ELSE 0 END) D_P_WH_RATE
FROM STATE_DEF SD
    LEFT JOIN TAX_DETAIL TD
        ON SD.TAX_DEF_ID = TD.TAX_DEF_ID
GROUP BY SD.TAX_DEF_ID, SD.EFFECTIVE_DATE
```

Comment: this is the uppercase of my answer :)))

Comment: No, my answer not a copy of yours. Look closer, you will get NULL instead of 0 if no TAX_DETAIL found for TAX_DEF` or no TAX_TYPE, DISTRIBUTION_TYPE combination for appropriated column.

Comment: I've not said is a copy. We answered the same time. But the answers look very similar.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Though there are other answers which are also correct, I am accepting it just because it would give me the output which I am looking for. I need I_S_WH_RATE and other columns to be zero when no child is present. This is great.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the result using `PIVOT`

```
select * From(
  select 
    a.TAX_DEF_ID, 
    a.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
    TAX_TYPE||DISTRIBUTION_TYPE AS TYP, 
    WH_RATE 
  From STATE_DEF a INNER JOIN TAX_DETAIL b ON a.TAX_DEF_ID=b.TAX_DEF_ID
)x 
PIVOT
(MAX(WH_RATE) as WH_RATE for (TYP) IN ('IS' AS I_S, 'IP' as I_P, 'DS' as D_S, 'DP' as D_P));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This answer also gives me correct result. I wish I could accept more answers :)

Comment: It's Okay... Happy to hear my Query gives desired output :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  tax_def_id,
  effective_date,
  sum(case when d.tax_type='I' and d.distribution_type='S' then wh_rate end) as I_S_WH_RATE
  --and so on...
from state_def t
join tax_detail d on (t.tax_def_id = d.tax_def_id)
group by   
   tax_def_id, 
   effective_date
```

Comment: No, my answer not a copy of yours. **Look closer**, you will get `NULL` instead of `0` if no `TAX_DETAIL found for `TAX_DEF` or no `TAX_TYPE`, `DISTRIBUTION_TYPE` combination for appropriated column.

Comment: The sum will be correct , however. And this is a difference between our answers, not a mistake. Many times a null is better than zero. Inexistence of value says something different than zero value.

Answer (score 0):

in 11g you can pivot this:

```
with data as (select s.TAX_DEF_ID, s.EFFECTIVE_DATE, d.TAX_TYPE, d.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE, d.WH_RATE
                from state_def s
                     inner join tax_detail d
                             on s.tax_def_id = d.tax_def_id)
select *
  from data
       pivot(max(wh_rate)
             for (TAX_TYPE, DISTRIBUTION_TYPE)
             in (('I', 'S') as I_S_WH_RATE,
                 ('I', 'P') as I_P_WH_RATE,
                 ('D', 'S') as D_S_WH_RATE,
                 ('D', 'P') as D_P_WH_RATE
                )
            );
```